¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar el pintado de la recta del foco de un Botón en un WinApi?
Al momento de crear un control de botón en una ventana principal se le adquieren ciertos parametros para su función normal; una de ellas es pintar la Recta del foco dentro del control, que no se especifica en ningún parametro para su estilo. ¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar esta respuesta del control?.
Un ejemplo sería el mismo pintado de un botón de un MessageBox, el cual al momento que se le da el foco del teclado no pinta la recta que se muestra a continuación:

Como se muestra en la imagen, el control obtiene una recta del foco

En este control simplemente muestra un botón de inserción con el estilo BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, pero no muestra una recta del foco como en la imagen anterior al momento de adquirir el foco del teclado.
Este es el código de mi programa ¿Qué tengo que agregar o modificar?:
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctl.h>

//Procedimiento de la ventana principal
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch(msg) 
    {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            HINSTANCE hInst=((LPCREATESTRUCT)lp)->hInstance;
            
            //Creación del control de botón en la ventana principal
            CreateWindowW(L"Button",
                          L"Continuar",
                          WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 
                          12,
                          12,
                          75,
                          22,
                          hwnd,
                          (HMENU)1,
                          hInst,
                          0 );
        } break;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE pInst,LPSTR cmd,int showCmd)
{
    WNDCLASS wc={0};
    wc.lpszClassName="cwnd";
    wc.lpfnWndProc=WinProc;
    wc.hInstance=hInst;
    wc.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    //Creación de la ventana principal
    HWND wnd=CreateWindowW(L"cwnd",
                           L"Window",
                           WS_VISIBLE|WS_SYSMENU|WS_CAPTION,
                           CW_DEFAULT,
                           CW_DEFAULT,
                           CW_DEFAULT,
                           CW_DEFAULT,
                           0,
                           0,
                           hInst,
                           0 );
    if(!wnd)return 0;
    ShowWindow(wnd,showCmd);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0)) 
    {
        if(!IsDialogMessage(wnd,&msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


Aquí hay una solución para C# que usa la API de C.
Deberías poder hacer algo similar. Tal vez así:
 HWND boton = CreateWindowW(L"Button",
                            L"Continuar",
                            WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 
                            12,
                            12,
                            75,
                            22,
                            hwnd,
                            (HMENU)1,
                            hInst,
                            0 );


SendMessage(boton, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, UIS_SET | UISF_HIDEFOCUS, 0);

Según la documentación, si el mensaje lo envías a una ventana se propaga por los demás elementos. Así que si en lugar de enviar el mensaje directamente al botón se lo enviases a la ventana matarías varios pájaros de un solo tiro.
